# Always get error "operating system is not supported by packagecloud.io, or this script's OS detection failed" when try to install from terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gitlab

I'm new in Ubuntu and Terminal. I try to install it:

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

**And get error when try to install it:**

```
Detected operating system as Ubuntu/zesty. Checking for curl... Detected curl... Running apt-get update... done. Installing apt-transport-https... done. Installing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list...curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found


Unable to download repo config from: https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/config_file.list?os=Ubuntu&dist=zesty&source=script

This usually happens if your operating system is not supported by  packagecloud.io, or this script's OS detection failed.

You can override the OS detection by setting os= and dist= prior to running this script. You can find a list of supported OSes and distributions on our website: https://packages.gitlab.com/docs#os_distro_version

For example, to force Ubuntu Trusty: os=ubuntu dist=trusty ./script.sh
```

I don't understand the error. I already try to find the solution but i still don't get the solution. Can anyone help me to explain why it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install?

Comment: @jos : I try to install it, https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/install

Comment: Why don't you just do `sudo apt install gitlab`?

Comment: "...operating system is not supported by packagecloud.io..." is very clear. Which part of it do you not understand? Which OS do you use?

Comment: @jos : i start to try install from here : https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604 , but i get error about packagecloud.io . I just want to try as suggest in documentation.

Comment: @mikewhatever : Are you have another way to install what i want to install? i want to learn more.

Comment: no one have solution?

Comment: I think the operating system is not supported because there is a *standard straightforward* way to install `gitlab` on your particular operating system. There is no need for complicated home-grown bash scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ubuntu version is "zesty", which is "17.10".
You are trying to download "gitlab-ce" from packagecloud using the script.
See: https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce

But: gitlab-ce is available at packagecloud only till xenial, which is "16.04 LTS". There is no package for "16.10" and "17.10".
They did not release an apt package for 17.10 till now.

Same problem I did have on 16.10, so I do not have a solution now (just explained the problem).

Edited:
You could try to download "gitlab" instead gitlab-ce, which is version 8.11.3, and is delivered out of the Ubuntu repository, not by packagecloud. Older version, I don't know if this is the community edition, but I think so.

See "apt-cache show gitlab".
Btw: You do not need the script for that, just enter "apt-get install gitlab". I will try on 16.10, didn't checked on 17.10.
But gitlab 8.11 does need a SSL and and NGinx Installation, which may cause more questions. Maybe switch to 16.04. I do not know.....

Edited again:
I tried "apt-get install gitlab" on 16.10 and ran into more errors (missing gems, and so on). The package "gitlab" is a non-supported version. See here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1720

So i skip, and will go back to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Greetings, Bernd.

Answer (score 2):

As @Bernd has explained why you get this error, try to override the os and dist values so you can go back to older distribution, it should fix the problem.
Try ubuntu/trusty like the following:

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo os=ubuntu dist=trusty bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y curl openssh-server ca-certificates 
sudo apt-get install -y postfix

curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo os=ubuntu dist=trusty bash


sudo EXTERNAL_URL="https://localhost/gitlab" apt-get install gitlab-ce
```